# Calculate Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

Why am I getting these two marked wrong?

Comment: I noticed I forgot a t in the third one.

Comment: What is the purpose of the down vote?

Comment: When you integrate the constant term $C$ you should get a linear term $Ct$

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you're asking a homework question

Comment: you are allowed to ask homework questions here, but only in a certain manner. See [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: I've attempted the work? I'm not asking anyone to solve it. I'm asking what I did wrong?

Comment: When going from $f''$ to $f'$ you need to integrate the constant term

Comment: @Sebz No work is shown only an incorrect answer

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to use pictures of your math. Rather, you should write it using MathJax.

Comment: Thanks Alex I figured it out

Comment: I'll try to ask better questions next time. Just frustrated from studying.

Answer (score 0):

First, the antiderivative of $C$ is $Ct,$ not $C.$

But maybe more importantly, what would $\text{“} \cdots+C+D\text{''}$ mean?

When you write something like $\displaystyle \int 3t^2\,dt =t^3+C,$ it means that $t^3$ is an antiderivative, and $3t^2+5$ is also an antiderivative, and $3t^2-42$ is also an antiderivative, and so on. So what would $\text{“ }t^3 + C+D\text{ ''}$ mean? Would there be some other antiderivatives identified by $\text{“ } t^3+C+D \text{ ''}$ that are not identified by $\text{“ } t^3+C \text{ ''?}$